# Show that the following sequence is unbounded.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, sobolev-spaces

> Suppose $u$ is in $H^1(\Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is a unit square  centered at the origin, such that it has singularity about the origin. As $C^1(\overline{\Omega}) $ is dense in $H^1(\Omega)$, we have a sequence $u_m$ such that $u_m \to u$ in the $H^1$ norm.
>
> Now, from [Rudins' Real and Complex Analysis](https://59clc.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/real-and-complex-analysis), theorem $3.12$, we have a subsequence $u_{m_i}$ of $u_m$ such that $u_{m_i} \to u$ pointwise almost everywhere.

Q1. Show that $u_m$ is unbounded.

Attempt: $u$ is unbounded in the neighborhood of zero say around an open ball $B(0;\epsilon)$, where $\epsilon \to 0$. Now, let $u_{m_i} \to u$ on $K$.  We then have $\mu(\Omega \setminus K)=0.$ Now as $\mu(B(0;\epsilon)) \neq 0$, choose $(x,y)\in K \cap B(0;\epsilon).$ Thus, we have by pointwise convergence there exists a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that 
$$
|u_{m_i}(x,y)-u(x,y)|< \epsilon \quad \forall i\ge N.
$$
Thus we have, $u_{m_i}$ is an unbounded sequence.

Am I correct upto this?

Thanks!

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: Some things are not too clear: 1) Unbounded with respect to which norm?  2) What is $K$?

Comment: @LorenzoQuarisa 1) Unbounded in the usual sense i.e. it grows arbitrarily large near the origin.    2) K is the region on which $u_{m_i} \to u$ pointwise.